# Embedding vector pruning: Obtaining a minimal set of embedding vectors required to describe a class

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, classification, word-embedding

I'm using a neural network to classify items based on the output embedding vectors from the network. L2 distance between embedding vectors is used to compute which class an item belongs to. My dataset has given me lots of embedding vectors per class, on the order of 10,000 embedding vectors per class, and I have 10 classes in total. Most of these embedding vectors 'overlap' in multidimensional space and are redundant. **What algorithms can I use to prune the the number of embedding vectors such that I can get a minimum viable set of vectors that fully describes each class?**

For example, 5 embedding vectors of a class might be sufficient to describe the class, how can I pick the 5 most optimal and descriptive vectors and prune the remaining 9995 (which mostly overlap with each other and are thus redundant)?